# express js mongoose model.find is undefined with es6

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

Here is my model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name:  String,
    email: String,
    provider:String,
    role:String
  });

  export default mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
```

In my controller

```
 import {UserModel} from './model'

 async getUser(req,res){

      UserModel.find((err,result)=>{
          console.log("Error",err);
      })
  }
```

I am getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are `export default`, you need to import with simply `import UserModel from './model'`.

`import { UserModel } from './model'` is for when you `export const UserModel = /* whatever */`, without the `default` keyword

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export for details

Comment: simple mistake :)